# Server closes connection before exec function in my php script finish executing

Tags: php, apache, exec

I have a PHP script that I have to execute from a browser. Inside that script, I use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function like this:

```
exec("sudo scriptname 2>&1", $out);
```

I want $out to hold the output returned by that script. I need the output for further processing. The script takes about 2 minutes to run. The problem is that when I run the PHP script in the browser, it keeps on running for a minute and then stops. Due to this, the PHP script dies and I get an error similar to 'Page not Responding'.

On chrome, the screen displays an error like this:

```
ServerName.com unexpectedly closed the connection
ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

On Mozilla, the screen goes blank (completely white).

After searching the chrome error, I do believe that the web server (I am running Apache) closes the connection due to inactivity from the client as the PHP script isn't really doing anything but waiting for the exec() function to finish.

I tried setting ***max_execution_time***, ***max_input_time***, ***default_socket_timeout*** and used ***set_time_limit(0)*** hoping that this might not kill the PHP script, but it didn't work.

I do not want to use PTHREADS to generate two threads where one runs the exec() function and the other monitors it or somehow keeps the server busy.

I believe there is some setting within PHP or apache that is set to 60 seconds, which kills the connection from the server. I just don't know what it is.

Also, the PHP script runs perfectly when I replace the script within exec() with another one that takes less than a minute.

**EDIT:** The Apache Timeout value is set to 120 seconds.

Comment: You are trying to execute PHP code on your browser? if so thats not possible, php is server code and you need javascript in the browser to run the server code and return the response from the server.

Comment: If it runs in Apache, check Timeout value.  This one will be triggered as well.  But realize that if a web site makes you wait for 2 minutes, you will stop, refresh your browser, leave the site, ...  Clients will not wait 2 mins.

Comment: I checked the Timeout value in httpd.conf. It is 120 seconds. So I guess that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance sudo is waiting for username/password input and is timing out after 1 min?

Comment: No. I have given Apache permission to execute the script without password. I tested that. If that is not the case, then the script terminates instantly and displays me the 'tty required' error.